# Validation isn't performed for wrong types in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here are relevant schema paths:

```
foo : {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Foo',
    validate: {
        validator: mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid,
        type: 'custom',
        message: 'proper foo is required'
    }
},
bar {
    type: Number,
    required: 'bar should be specified'
}
```

When `foo` is submitted as empty string (which is default value), validation error is thrown:

> "Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "foo" ...

And validator isn't triggered in this case. Even if `validator` is changed to `() => false`, it doesn't have a chance to provide readable `message`.

But it becomes fine when `null` is provided instead of empty string. I would prefer to avoid preprocessing `foo` if this can be handled by validation alone.

Same error appears in numeric field, `bar`:

> Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "bar" ...

Why are validators not being triggered? Is this behaviour configurable? How can incorrect data types can be handled here, so human-friendly message could be given?

Comment: is foo a required property? or should '' not throw any error for you?

Comment: @AndyMacleod Yes, it is required, and I expect that `''` invalid value will be handled later by a validator which can give a meaningful message instead of `Cast to...`.

Comment: required is the only validator that is run on undefined (and null I believe) values. you can add required to ensure that it is there

Comment: @AndyMacleod Yes. The problem is that it is not undefined but empty string (it comes from a form), so type error appears instead of 'proper foo is required'. I guess there were other validator on `bar` besides `required` in my case.